# Один домен, два сервера

Tags: redirect, debian

Все привет, есть два выделенных сервера и один домен, домен проделегирован к первому серверу, можно ли, изменяя настройки первого сервера, сделать, чтобы при обращении к этому домену реально работал другой сервер? без переделегирования

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

организовать простое проксирование

Comment: это через конфиг апача можно сделать?

Comment: [можно](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)